# delete a facebook feed post using fb_graph gem

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, rubygems, fb-graph

I am using [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) rails gem for posting a message to my user's Facebook feed.

I have requested the following permissions:

```
:scope => 'email, publish_actions, offline_access, publish_stream'
```

I am able to post to the user's feed. But I am unable to destroy it.

When I execute the following in the Rails Console you can see the errors:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me( user.access_token )
@facebookpost = me.feed!( :message => "sample feed message", :description => 'sample message')
post = me.feed.find(@facebookpost.identifier).first

post.destroy # this generates the following error

FbGraph::InvalidRequest: OAuthException :: (#100) Invalid parameter
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/exception.rb:47:in `block in handle_httpclient_error'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/exception.rb:44:in `each'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/exception.rb:44:in `handle_httpclient_error'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:146:in `handle_response'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:63:in `delete'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:43:in `destroy'
from (irb):67
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

  1.9.2-p318 :068 > post.destroy(user.access_token)
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into String
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:93:in `delete'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:93:in `build_endpoint'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:61:in `delete'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/fb_graph-2.4.12/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:43:in `destroy'
from (irb):68
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/invinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Did I miss any permissions? What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete posts with

```
FbGraph::Post.new(fb_post_id).destroy(access_token: "access_token")
```

Not the best API though...

Answer (score 0):

The v2.4 requires that you combine the fb_post_id with the client id.

`FbGraph2::Post.new("#{client_id}_#{fb_post_id}", access_token: "access_token").destroy`